# PHP How to write values from different input types in a form in the appearing order to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, input

I have a form where the amount of `input type="file"` and `textarea` inputs and the order of these inputs are variable; they are added dynamically into a form. The values of these inputs are saved to a mysql database trough `method="POST"`.

I have given the inputs the same array name, like this `name="longcopy[]"` hoping that it creates an array with values in order of appearance.

As an example:

```
<input type="file" name="longcopy[]" accept="image/*">
<textarea name="longcopy[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="longcopy[]"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="longcopy[]" accept="image/*">
<textarea name="longcopy[]"></textarea>
```

and after submitting, I was hoping for an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => img1.jpg,
    [1] => text1, 
    [2] => text2, 
    [3] => img2.jpg, 
    [4] => text3
)
```

So the values of the array can be saved to a database in the right order. For some reason it only works on the textareas…

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Files are accessible through `$_FILES`. They won't be in `$_POST` like the textarea values. And you need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form.

Comment: If it's variable, how can you know which element holds which value? Frankly, it's a very bad idea. You have to rethink your design.

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` I have. Thank you for your answer, it looks it can't be done the way I want to…

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you. I want to find a way for people creating a way of writing text and posting images in a flexible order and flexible amount…

Comment: Flexible amount is fair. Flexible order doesn't make any sense. Is your database structure "flexible" as well?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes for the moment I am writing the name of the image and the textarea values to an table called _paragraph_ all of them with the same _post ID_ and each with an _ID_ with _Auto Increment_ which creates the order of appearance for each kind of input. There is an extra column where it saves _txt_ wenn the input is a textarea and _img_ wenn it is a file…

Comment: SO there *is* an order. then you can name all textareas as `text[]`, all images as `image[]` and so on.

Comment: @YourCommonSense allright, but how can PHP "know" if let's say one `text[]` comes first then two times an `image[]` followed by one `text[]` which again is followed by an `image[]`… that is something i can't figure out…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are accessible through `$_FILES`. They won't be in `$_POST` like the `<textarea/>` values. Each set of variables will be indexed separately.

If you wan't to preserve order you need to define indices explicitly.

```
<input type="file" name="longcopy[0]" accept="image/*">
<textarea name="longcopy[1]"></textarea>
<textarea name="longcopy[2]"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="longcopy[3]" accept="image/*">
<textarea name="longcopy[4]"></textarea>
```

Then put `$_FILES` and `$_POST` together:

```
$longcopy_files = array_map("save_file_and_return_path", diverse_array($_FILES['longcopy']));
$longcopy = $_POST['longcopy'] + $longcopy_files;
ksort($longcopy);
print_r($longcopy);
```

Which results in:

> ```
> Array
> (
>    [0] => uploads/file_1.jpeg
>    [1] => first textarea
>    [2] => second textarea
>    [3] => uploads/file_2.png
>    [4] => third textarea
> )
> ```

*Note: `diverse_array` function is from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#109958).*